# Назначить property в спринг с помощью @PropertySource

Tags: spring, java

Как читать инфу из propery файла с помощью аннотаций? Делаю, [как тут](http://kruders.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-using-annotation/), свой пример сильно упростил, но и он не работает. Имеются такие классы:

```
public class Customer {

private String name;

public Customer() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}}
```

Конфигурационный:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("database.properties")
public class AppConfiguration {
  @Value("#{jdbc.username}")
  private String name;

  @Bean(name = {"customerBean"})
  @Scope(value = "prototype")
  @DependsOn({"conf"})
  public Customer customer() {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setName(name);
    return customer;
  }

  @Bean(name = {"conf"})
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer conf() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer conf
            = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    return conf;
}}
```

Файл properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mk
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
```

лежит в папке target/classes, как на рисунке:

[image]

При попытке получить доступ к полю бина customerBean.getName лезут исключения -

`Property or field 'jdbc' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?`

И не понимаю, почему так. Если сделать бин conf non-static, то исключение более не лезет, но поле customerBean.getName == null. Какой нормальный подход к этому?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче, я неправильно указал параметр  `@Value("#{jdbc.username}")`. Вместо `#` надо было использовать `$`. Всё заработало. Нефиг всякие левые гайды читать. :(

Answer (score -1):

Сделайте бин `conf` static. Если автовайринг не работает, то попробуйте вынести этот кусок в другой конфиг, возможно, в нем заработает.

Comment: ноль эффекта

Comment: А разве `setLocations()` на `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` не надо вызывать, чтобы он знал, из каких property-файлов значения брать?

Comment: @PropertySource("database.properties") в начале файла.

Comment: Больше у меня идей нет. В моем проекте со статическим методом все работает. Соответственно, предлагаю вам подебажить самостоятельно: выкрутить логгирование на максимум, может, там что будет, пройтись дебаггером по спрингу или почитать исходный код `BeanExpressionContext`.